# Scipy Compute Mann Whitney U along Multiple Slices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy.stats

Given the following arrays:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import mannwhitneyu

s1 = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,0,10],[10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]])
s2 = np.array([[1,11,3,7,5,6,7,8,0,10],[10,9,8,7,6,15,4,13,2,1]])
```

I want to run the Mann-Whitney(-Wilcoxon) U test once for each slice of the respective samples and have the results populate into one output array with one slice for the U statistic and the other for the p-value.
I know I can run them individually like this:

```
r1 = mannwhitneyu(s1[0], s2[0])
r2 = mannwhitneyu(s1[1], s2[1])
```

Output:

```
MannwhitneyuResult(statistic=39.5, pvalue=0.2239039981060696)
MannwhitneyuResult(statistic=37.0, pvalue=0.17162432050520815)
```

Desired output:

```
array([39.5, 0.2239039981060696], [ 37.0, 0.17162432050520815])
```

I have tried `np.apply_along_axis` but the array argument only takes one input and I have 2.
Also, I need the fastest solution possible as I'll be doing this over thousands of slices as part of a simulation.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `map(...)`, is the best choice, and quite faster than, `np.apply_along_axis(...)`, as it uses a [python loop](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/fb215c76967739268de71aa4bda55dd1b062bc2e/numpy/lib/shape_base.py#L401) internally, and some of a computationally expensive ops **i.e.** `transpose(...)` and `view(...)`, so under usual circumstances even looping through Numpy array using python loop, would be faster.

---

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import mannwhitneyu

s1 = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,0,10],[10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]])
s2 = np.array([[1,11,3,7,5,6,7,8,0,10],[10,9,8,7,6,15,4,13,2,1]])

idx = np.arange(len(s1))
```

---

```
def step(i):

  return [*mannwhitneyu(s1[i], s2[i])]
```

---

```
np.array(list(map(step, idx)))
```

Comment: What does the asterisk do in the return command? I tried this with a custom function I made but had to remove the asterisk to get it to work.

Comment: Asterisk unpacks the iterable object, you might check the output array, shape if you remove it, `np.array(list(map(step, idx))).shape`