# Numpy Apply Custom Function Along Axis (or Map)

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy

[Related to this question:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66190182/scipy-compute-mann-whitney-u-along-multiple-slices)

I have the following code with custom functions:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad
from scipy.special import binom
from scipy.stats import norm
import math as mt
ranks = np.array([[8, 5, 3, 7, 6, 2, 1, 4],
       [8, 5, 3, 7, 6, 2, 1, 4]])

def E(r, n):
    print(r,n)
    def f(x):
        F = Phi(x)
        return x*(1-F)**(r-1)*F**(n-r)*phi(x)
    return -r*binom(n, r)*quad(f, -inf, inf)[0]
```

I want to apply the function E over each row of the array `ranks`.

I tried `np.apply_along_axis` but the problem I'm having is that I have 2 arguments for the function: the individual rank of an element in a row of an array (`r`) and the length of that row (`n`).

Also, I'm wondering if it would be faster and better anyway to use `map` as with the accepted answer to the question referenced above (because speed is important with this).

**Here's what I've tried:**

```
result = np.apply_along_axis(E, 1, ranks)
```

Issue: I need to provide the `n` argument. Also, this may be slower than mapping.

```
#not sure if the "*" is needed or what it does.
def E2(i):
    return [*E(ranks[i], len(ranks[i]))]

it = 2 #2 rows (iterations)
indx = np.arange(it)
result = np.array(list(map(E2, indx)))
```

Issue: Needs 1 rank at a time, per row. Not sure how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If I understand you correctly, n is `len(r)`, so it's superfluous to pass that information. It should be just calculated in the fuction internally.

Comment: `apply_along_axis` is **not** a speed tool.  It may be convenient when iterating over 2 or more dimensions (of a 3d+ array), but it does not make the iteration faster.  If it isn't convenient to use, forget it.   I prefer list comprehension over map for its expresiveness.

Comment: @Reti43 I'm open to trying that, but it would mean I'd need to pass each element of the row and the row itself to the function for each value of the row.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't specified the imports for `Phi`, `quad` etc, I won't try to provide a working example.

```
def E(r, n):
    print(r,n)
    def f(x):
        F = Phi(x)
        return x*(1-F)**(r-1)*F**(n-r)*phi(x)
    return -r*binom(n, r)*quad(f, -inf, inf)[0]
```

A simple list comprehension:

```
res = [E(r,n) for r in ranks]
```

I'd prefer to move the `f(x)` definition out of `E`.  That may be more of a matter of style than performance.

```
def f(x,r):
    F = Phi(x)
    return x*(1-F)**(r-1)*F**(n-r)*phi(x)

def E(r,n):
    temp = quad(f, -inf, inf, args=(r,))[0]
    return -r*binom(n, r)*temp
```

Comment: So sorry. I've added the imports.